# Performance issue in Sun OS

Tags: saxon

I transforming an XML to XML using SAXON9EE.  Size of source file is 200MB, Size of XSL is 65KB
The translation time is different on different machines.

1. On Windwows Vista, 64bit, 24GB RAM takes 4hrs
2. On Windows XP, 32bit, 4GB RAM takes 6hrs
3. On Linux 32 bit, 8GB RAM takes 14hrs
4. **On Sun OS, 64bit, 32GB RAM takes 48hrs.  Here are some output from Sun OS TOP command 309 processes: 290 sleeping, 3 zombie, 3 stopped,
   13 on cpu CPU states: 63.6% idle, 35.0% user,  1.4% kernel,  0.0%
   iowait,  0.0% swap Memory: 32G phys mem, 10G free mem, 4005M total
   swap, 4005M free swap**
5. On another Sun OS, 64bit, 8GB RAM, takes 48hrs.

My requirement is to run on Sun OS and reduce the time.  Why does Sun OS take such a long time.  I have tried changing the heap size, no luck.  Should I try changing any other parameter.
Please advice.
Thanks
Regards
Siva

Comment: This takes too long on all the machines for a file of that size. Have you tried to optimize your XSLT with indexes?

Comment: Can you please give the syntax or let me know the procedure.

Comment: There's plenty of documentation out there. Look for "xslt key index". Once you have an initial version and still run into performance problems come back here you will be helped.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Did some reading. All the explanations were requesting to identify the key and modify the XSL file. Due to a knowledge gap in the source file and XSL, this is not possible. My biggest concern is why its taking huge time in SUN OS

Comment: You have asked the same question on the Saxonica support channel, and we will progress it there.